# How do I set fx:controller property in gluon's scenebulder?

Tags: javafx-8, scenebuilder, gluon

It seems to be completely missing from the code properties, see screenshot below. I realise I can do this by clicking Text and putting it in manually, but given I can set `fx:id` in the Code properties I would have thought I could do the same with `fx:controller`. Or is it hidden somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it under the Documents Panel: View -> Show Document or Ctrl+5

Comment: Thanks, actually in SceneBuilder that has been built into IntelliJ you cannot see this, but with the "proper" gluon app it can be seen tucked away under the other components